# Issue with parsing publication data from PubMed with Entrez

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, pubmed

I am trying to use Entrez to import publication data into a database. The search part works fine, but when I try to parse:

```
from Bio import Entrez

def create_publication(pmid):

    handle = Entrez.efetch("pubmed", id=pmid, retmode="xml")
    records = Entrez.parse(handle)
    item_data = records.next()
    handle.close()
```

... I get the following error:

> File
>   "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/Entrez/Parser.py",
>   line 296, in parse
>       raise ValueError("The XML file does not represent a list. Please use Entrez.read instead of Entrez.parse") ValueError: The XML file
>   does not represent a list. Please use Entrez.read instead of
>   Entrez.parse

This code used to work until a few days ago. Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

Also, looking at the source code (http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Entrez-pysrc.html) and trying to follow the listed example, gives the same error:

```
from Bio import Entrez 
Entrez.email = "Your.Name.Here@example.org"
handle = Entrez.efetch("pubmed", id="19304878,14630660", retmode="xml")    
records = Entrez.parse(handle) 
for record in records: 
    print(record['MedlineCitation']['Article']['ArticleTitle']) 
handle.close()
```

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried using `Entrez.read()`, and then parsing the results?

Comment: read() works principally, but there is a whole bunch of other code around this. So when I try, I just keep getting different errors. So either there is a simple fix for parse(), or I need to rewrite the rest.

Comment: This used to work until three days ago, but it seems something changed at PubMed recently, so it fails now.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I'm getting the same error with the second bit of code you posted. `records` is a generator object, but I can't seem to read it, so I'm not sure what it contains...

Comment: Yep, same here. I'll go for read() then. But maybe I try to get in touch with people at NIH who run PubMed. If they made the change deliberately, then it is fine. But it could also be a bug they are not aware of.

Comment: Looks like [biopython devs are aware](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/1027)

Comment: Thanks Kevin for sharing the link!

Comment: @apiljic the [GitHub  Issue](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/1027) is now closed, just FYI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue, as documented in other comments and the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/1027), is caused by a deliberate change made by NCBI Entrez Utilities Developers. As documented in this issue by Jhird , you can change your code to the following:

```
from Bio import Entrez 
Entrez.email = "Your.Name.Here@example.org"
handle = Entrez.efetch("pubmed", id="19304878,14630660", retmode="xml")  

records = Entrez.read(handle)      # Difference here
records = records['PubmedArticle'] # New line here  

for record in records: 
    print(record['MedlineCitation']['Article']['ArticleTitle']) 
handle.close()
```